# CSS proportional images behaving differently on Chrome and Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, image-resizing

I have a div with an image inside. Images have varied sizes and orientation, I want the images to resize proportionally if the image size is larger than the frame (images should retain the original size if they are smaller than the frame).

My problem is the image does not resize proportionally in Firefox (image is no longer proportional, height increases if the image width goes over the max-width property, though the width respects the max-width property), but looks fine on Chrome.

I'm not sure if this could be fixed with CSS alone, but a CSS-only solution would be preferred if there is any.

**CODE**

```css
.frame {
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  border: 10px solid #333;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.frame img {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 160px 160px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  max-width: 140px;
  max-height: 140px;
}
```

```html
<div class="frame">
  <img src="//s3.amazonaws.com/ssiCebu/Confirmit/APAC/2015/May/23991558_LowRateRepricing/cards/1.jpg" />
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="frame">
  <img src="//i.bnet.com/blogs/vertical_farm_in_desert_chris_jacobs.jpg" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is working fiddle for your example: https://jsfiddle.net/tjmrmLcc/2/

Try and edit following CSS rule

```
.frame img {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 160px 160px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
   width:100% /*Added Rule*/
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 140px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, though I tested it and it works on the first image. But I tested it on portrait-oriented image, and it did not scale proportionally (I added another example image). Is there a way to make it compatible with portrait images as well?

Comment: Your newly added image is missing. can you check the path again?

Comment: I'm not sure, the image below the first one is visible on my end. This is the path used: http://i.bnet.com/blogs/vertical_farm_in_desert_chris_jacobs.jpg